# "Output" com caracteres especiais

Tags: c, codificação-de-caracteres, gcc

Estou utilizando o compilador GCC versão 5.3 para o seguinte programa, redigido no Aptana:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    int positivo = 32767;
    int negativo = -32768;

    printf("%d +1 é %d\n", positivo, positivo+1);
    printf("%d -1 é %d\n", negativo, negativo-1); 
}
```

Com a seguinte saída:

[image: tela com resultado]

Já no bloco de texto, com a seguinte:

[image: tela com resultado]

Como devo proceder para que os caracteres sejam exibido corretamente ?

Comment: Provávelmente problemas de compatibilidade de "encodings" dos terminal, editores de texto... (em que ambientes estás?)

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, o que quer dizer com "ambientes" ? @JJoao

Comment: Em windows, linha de comando, podes definir qual o charset usado (exemplo windows-CP1252, unicode-utf8, etc) nos editores de texto podes selecionar o carser/encoding (exemplo ansi, etc). Em linux e mac as configurações têm valores iniciais mais razoáveis mas tambem são configuráveis. Sugestão ir comutanto tudo para o mesmo charset/encoding -- talvez unicode-uft8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente precisa usar um [`setlocale()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale) para permitir o uso de caracteres acentuados.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void) {
    int positivo = 32767;
    int negativo = -32768;
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    printf("%d +1 é %d\n", positivo, positivo + 1);
    printf("%d -1 é %d\n", negativo, negativo - 1); 
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4cm69G). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ovybmgwv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Accent.c).

Mas não é vantagem alguma porque eles já funcionavam sem o `setlocale()`. Não tive como testar nas suas condições para reproduzir o problema.

Comment: Essa solução funciona perfeitamente no bloco de notas, já no Aptana ele trocou por outro, também especial... E também notei, que trocastes `void` por `main` e ainda especificou um tipo, pode dizer por que ?

Comment: Provavelmente precisa configurar o editor de texto para gravar com outra codificação, um deles está gravando errado, mas aí já é outro problema.

Comment: E qual o motivo das trocas que fez ?

Comment: Acertar a codificação de caracteres, só que você tem que gravar todos seus fontes com a mesma, senão vira loucura, cada vez que salvar o fonte em um editor diferente, tem que mudar o código para lidar com isto, o que é um completo absurdo.

Comment: @bigown, parecia-me que se trata essencialmente de uma questão de encoding e da sua compatibilização entre editor e terminal.